# Why cakephp image uploader plugin isnot working?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to upload image during ajax call. For this, I used a plugin for thumb nail creation.But Its not inserting any data and thumbnail also.

I am giving my plugin link and also controller code and model :

https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

```
$club_id = $this->request->data['Photo']['club_id'];
$id = $this->Auth->user();
$this->request->data['Photo']['user_id'] = $id["id"];
$this->request->data['Photo']['club_id'] = $club_id;
$this->request->data['Photo']['photo_type'] = "club";
$this->request->data['Photo']['profile_picture'] = "no";
$this->Photo->save($this->request->data);
```

AND MODEL CODE :

```
public $actsAs = array(
     'Upload.Upload' => array(
          'picture' => array(
           'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
             'fields' => array(
               'dir' => 'picture_dir'
                 ),                
                 'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                    'thumb' => '100x100'
                  ), 'thumbnailMethod' => 'php'
          )
     )
  );
```

My view file is :

```
$this->Form->create($id, array('type' => 'file', "id" => "multiform"));
$this->Form->input('picture', array('type' => 'file'));
$this->Form->button('Upload', array('type' => 'submit', "id" => "club_upload"));
$this->Form->end();
```

Its not creating thumbnail and data in database. I am stuck on it, any idea would help me.

Comment: Getting any errors (error/debug log)? Uploading the picture WITHOUT ajax, is that of any help? Because image uploading through ajax requires a little bit different code than a standard POST request :)

Comment: No, I am not getting any error!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
        'fields' => array(
            'dir' => 'picture_dir'
        ),
        'thumbnailSizes' => array(
            'thumb' => '100x100'
        ),
        'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
        'deleteOnUpdate'  => true
    )
);
```

**EDIT:**

In view file:

```
$this->Form->create('Photo', array('type' => 'file', "id" => "multiform"));
```

Passing `id` as form name is bad idea.

Now you can access your data like this:

```
 $this->request->data['Photo']['picture']
```

You may have add form for `club_id` field.

Comment: Its not working, ITS NOT SAVING ANY data into database,also not creating any folder

Comment: @CrazyMan Could you add View file with Form?

Comment: @CrazyMan any errors? check `app/tmp/logs/error.log`